# Is it possible to deny a collection document update from a specific page?

Tags: meteor

I send users to a receipt page after they make a donation the receipt page URL is formatted this way `https://hostname/thanks/:_id` (where :_id is the mongodb document id). From this page I don't want them to be able to run an update, insert or remove from the console. Right now I can run the below successfully.

`Donate.update('yozLsubzoRXYqMeh6', {$set: {'debit.status': 'failed'}});`

Can I use a deny rule to block the update, insert and remove actions?

Answer (score 0):

You can use an allow/deny rule to block access to a certain object based on its state, but you cannot create one that would take the current url into account. The thing is, as you've noticed, anyone with access to a browser console can run any arbitrary command. The allow/deny rules are there to ensure the server-side data is secure even if the client code has been tampered with, and thus they consider each operation on atomic level.

So in your case you can just current state of donation, current user, and deny all updates to a complete donation made by non-admin users.

Comment: I don't require a user account to make a donation. Is there another way to deny updating, maybe I need to move all of my insert and update calls from the client code into the server code?

Comment: I just moved all my code insert and update code into the server and set the allow and deny rules to not allow inserting, updating and removing. This works.